# AES product function

Tags: aes

Small description:

consider a polynomial in GF($2^8$) , which has the form $$f(x) = b_7x^7 + b6x^6 + b_{5}x^5 + b_4x^4 + b_3x^3 + b_2x^2 + b_1x + b_0 $$ If we multiply by x , we have
    $$x * f(x) = (b_7x^8 + b_6x^7 + b_5x^6 + b_4x^5 + b_3x^4 + b_2x^3 + b_1x^2 + b_0x) mod m(x)$$

If b$_7$ = 0, then the result is a polynomial of degree less than 8, which is already in reduced form, and no further computation is necessary. If $b_7$ = 1, then reduce modulo m(x) .

$$ x * f(x) = (b_6x^7 + b_5x^6 + b_4x^5 + b_3x^4 + b_2x^3 + b_1x^2 + b_0x) + (x4 + x3 + x + 1)$$

This is an example:

$f(x) = x^6 +x^4 +x^2 + x + 1$

$g(x)= x^7 + x + 1$
$m(x) = x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1$

$f(x) * g(x) = (01010111) * (10000011)$

we determine the results of multiplication by powers of :

$(01010111) * (00000010) = (10101110)$

$(01010111) * (00000100) = (01011100) \oplus (00011011) = (01000111)$

$(01010111) * (00001000) = (10001110)$

$(01010111) * (00010000) = (00011100) \oplus (00011011) = (00000111)$

$(01010111) * (00100000) = (00001110)$

$(01010111) * (01000000) = (00011100)$

$(01010111) * (10000000) = (00111000)$

So

$(01010111) * (10000011) = (01010111) *[(00000001) \oplus (00000010) \oplus (10000000)]$
$= (01010111) \oplus (10101110) \oplus (00111000) = (11000001)$

which is equivalent to $x^7 + x^6 + 1$

I understand why we have $(00000001) \oplus (00000010) \oplus (10000000) $ but I don’t understand how is calculated :

(01010111) * (00000100) =   .... 
(01010111) * (00001000) =   ....

And so go on…

Someone can explain how (01010111) * (00000100) is calculated?

Thanks
sss

Comment: One way is $(01010111)\times(00000100) = (01010111)\times(00000010)\times(00000010)$ - you already know how to evaluate the right side.  We know this is true because $(00000100)= (00000010)\times(00000010)$

Comment: Perfect... really thanks now i have understand. I take the previous result and i use a left shift +1.